# How to evaluate the following gaussian integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, holomorphic-functions, gaussian-integral

$$\int dz^{*}dz \exp\bigg[-(z^{*}z-cz^{*}-zd^{*})\bigg] $$ In the above integral,$$z,z^{*},c,d^{*} \in \mathbb{C} $$. As this a gaussian integral one can do this by completing the squares. However here there is an issue. The argument in the exponential is not of the form $(z^{*}z-cz^{*}-zc^{*})$. So how do one solve this integral by completing the squares. Can someone help me in evaluting this integral

Answer (score 0):

Using the coordinate transformation
$$z=x+iy, \qquad z^{*}=x-iy,$$
the integral can be transformed to an integral over $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/308929/interpretation-of-double-complex-integral)):
$$\begin{align}
\int \exp\Bigl[{-z^{*}z+cz^{*}+d^{*}z}\Bigr] dz^{*} dz &\propto\int \exp\Bigl[{-(x-iy)(x+iy)+c(x-iy)+d^{*}(x+iy)}\Bigr] dx dy\\
&= \int e^{-x^2+(c+d^{*})x} e^{-y^2+i(d^{*}-c)y} dx dy
\end{align}$$

By completing the square separately for $x$ and $y$, we then obtain
$$\begin{align}
\int e^{-x^2+(c+d^{*})x} dx \int e^{-y^2+i(d^{*}-c)y} dy &= \sqrt{\pi} e^{\frac{(c+d^{*})^2}{4}} \times \sqrt{\pi} e^{\frac{-(d^{*}-c)^2}{4}}\\
&= \pi e^{cd^*}
\end{align}$$